# WordPress' ALL post count info on its dashboard does not match phpMyAdmin's ALL post count!

Tags: posts, wp-admin, dashboard

While phpmyadmin's wp_posts table reports something like this

```
Showing rows 0 - 29 (10,223 total, Query took 0.0022 sec)
SQL query:
SELECT * FROM  `wp_posts` LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Wordpress's dashboard reports

```
All (10,222) | Published (10,222)
Search Posts:  10,222 items « ‹  of 512 › »
```

As you can see, there is a disconnect here... 10,222 != 10,223

Does anyone know why WordPress reports 1 less then the actual all post count?

Comment: You seem to [have found an answer in wp-hackers list](http://lists.automattic.com/pipermail/wp-hackers/2012-June/043357.html)... Would you mind sharing the answer here?

Comment: will do. if you be patient, you do not have to worry about these things...  if you look at some of my old answers, i answer the questions that i myself asked for the other's benefit. these things are a matter of time.. stay cool, we'll do it.

Comment: Downvote removed. I raised the flag as it would keep anyone from researching for something that already had tons of feedback at wp-lists... Thanks for reporting back!

Answer (score 1):

It all comes down to this.
http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/11889

Behind the scenes, WordPress does generate a place-holder post for your next one! And for that special post, it sets the post_status to a special one,  'auto-draft'. Basically, the culprit is the post generated by WordPress without your knowledge.

Once you know this fact, it is easy to understand why there is a disconnect. Wordpress admin screen's ALL count info is based on ALL posts except this special one. WordPress's SQL's `WHERE` excludes the post whose `post_status`='auto-draft'.

Whereas, phpMyAdmin's SQL's `WHERE` **needless to say**, totally lacks this condition, and hence we end up with the -1 disconnect between the two ALL post counts, causing guys like me the WTH situation.

So under the hood, the cause of the disconnect is this...

```
select count(*) from `wp_posts`
```

vs

```
select count(*) from `wp_posts` where `post_status` <> 'auto-draft'
```